# Si un campo number incrementa que incremente otro campo number automatico en javaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo dos campos de tipo number y quiero que cuando al primer campo le añadan 1, se incremente en el otro campo tambien y viseversa.

```
 <input type='number' class='colLg20 colMd20 colSm20 colXs20 chip' name='cantidadMsisdnPedidos' id='cantidadMsisdnPedidos' placeholder='CANTIDAD' onKeypress='return soloNumeros(event);'/>

<input type='number' name='cantidadChips' id='cantidadChips' placeholder='CANTIDAD' onKeypress='return soloNumeros(event);'/>

$('#cantidadMsisdnPedidos').on("keyup", function(){
    
    $('#cantidadChips').html(this.value);
  });
```

Comment: Agrega el código `JS` con el que has intentado. Sólo es necesario capturar el `value` de cada `input` con el evento `onKeypress` e incrementarlo en el otro.

Comment: Yendo a otro extremo: ¿reactividad?

Comment: algo asi intento

Comment: ya salio ya me jalo asi

Comment: Parece algo simple como para recurrir a esto pero parece una buena ocasión para implementar un `Observable`

Comment: y como se podria añadir??